# What is a DC block and how can I put this on a PCB?

Tags: pcb, rf, surface-mount

The circuit diagram that I am trying to replicate casually mentions a component called "DC block" but doesn't go into details.  I believe this has something to do with RF filtering?  Will I be able to solder a component onto a PCB to perform this function?  The component is located at the RF_in pin of a GNSS module.

page 15 of the document below
[hardware integration](https://www.u-blox.com/en/docs/UBX-15030059)

[image: circuit]

Comment: "Block" in this case means block as in obstruct. To prevent from passing. The only component in the diagram that is performing the DC block operation is the 47 pF capacitor. Reach out to the antenna and/or GPS module vendor to see if they will review your schematic and/or BOM, and/or layout. They might. Sometimes you can learn a lot from applications engineers working for vendors. It is one of the ways that electrical engineers increase their knowledge over time.

Comment: The name is written right beside a capacitor. So just fit a capacitor : DC Block just describes its purpose there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just what the symbol shows, a 47pF capacitor (which blocks DC from the bias supply). Use any small SMT part rated for adequate voltage (eg. 0603 NP0 type).

Bias is typically something like +5V, so a typical 50V-rated capacitor is more than adequate.